# Google OAuth 2.0 for WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, email

How would one send an email from google to other users when they register.

Website to get all this info: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/

What I currently have:

1. Client ID
2. Client Secret + json file
3. API Key
4. `using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;`

Is this all I need to create the OAuth 2.0? And how would I?
Every tutorial states some use for p12 key which I do not have nor can find.